# Setting a particular date into a prepared statement

Tags: java, date, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert any given date into my prepared statement in this format(e.g. 11/08/1989, 04/15/1955)

Heres my code:

```
pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user_info VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

pstmnt.setInt(1, max_id);
            pstmnt.setString(2, f_name);
            pstmnt.setString(3, l_name);
            pstmnt.setString(4, email);
            pstmnt.setString(5, username);
            pstmnt.setDate(6, ?);
            pstmnt.addBatch();
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this, given a lot of the Date methods are deprecated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `java.sql.Date` object to the `setDate()` method .

```
pstmt.setDate(6, 
          new java.sql.Date(( new
                 SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("11/08/1989")).getTime()));
```

Comment: Hang on I think it was my error, I'll get back to you in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
pstmt.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date(
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("11/08/1989")));
```

Comment: The compiler gives the error "incompatible types: java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date"